# Spell Checker for Persian Languages in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, spell-checking

Is there any spell checker library for .NET which really supports Arabic script languages? Or any working example?

I want to spell check the words in a rich text box in VB.net.

Answer (score 1):

I think [NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/) will help you. It has many languages, including [Persian](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries#Persian_.28Iran.29_2).

Comment: May be it work with Pesian, is there any example how to use NHunspell in Vb.net?

Comment: Try this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33658/NHunspell-Hunspell-for-the-NET-platform). It's C#, but it should be easy to write in VB.NET code.